# Lag in SKNode runAction:completion: in recursive method

Tags: ios, objective-c, recursion, sprite-kit, skaction

Please consider the following recursion:

```
- (void)addFlashActionToLampWithLampIndex:(int)index {
    LampNode *lamp = (LampNode *)self.children[index];
    int nextLampIndex = index + 1;
    if (nextLampIndex > self.children.count - 1) {
        nextLampIndex = 0;
    }

    SKAction *flash = [SKAction runBlock:^{
        NSLog(@"2");
    }];
//    SKAction *wait = [SKAction waitForDuration:0.015f];

    NSLog(@"1");
    [self runAction:flash completion:^{
        [self addFlashActionToLampWithLampIndex:nextLampIndex];
    }];
}
```

Output:

```
2014-03-27 20:51:21.104 SpinNWin[15811:60b] 1
2014-03-27 20:51:21.110 SpinNWin[15811:60b] 2
2014-03-27 20:51:21.110 SpinNWin[15811:60b] 1
2014-03-27 20:51:21.143 SpinNWin[15811:60b] 2
2014-03-27 20:51:21.144 SpinNWin[15811:60b] 1
2014-03-27 20:51:21.177 SpinNWin[15811:60b] 2
2014-03-27 20:51:21.177 SpinNWin[15811:60b] 1
2014-03-27 20:51:21.210 SpinNWin[15811:60b] 2
2014-03-27 20:51:21.210 SpinNWin[15811:60b] 1
2014-03-27 20:51:21.243 SpinNWin[15811:60b] 2
```

I'm expecting an execution of that method to be instant, without any delays or lags. However, as you can notice, there is a lag between `NSLog(@"1");` and `NSLog(@"2");` for about 0.03 sec.

Does anyone has ideas why this is happening and how to avoid this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because actions need time to progress. Actions are evaluated after the SKScene's `update:` method runs:

[image]
(Source: [Sprite Kit Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsAnimation/Conceptual/SpriteKit_PG/Actions/Actions.html))

Therefore if you do runAction: the action will not run until after the scene's update method. Depending on whether you run the action somewhere within the `update:` message chain, or in `didEvaluateActions` or `didSimulatePhysics` Sprite Kit may render one frame without having yet run the action.

Comment: When I test on my device, lag time decreases to 0.015, while FPS increases from ~30 to 60, so may be you're right about that. Do you have any thoughts how to avoid that?

Comment: It depends on what you're trying to do with the recursive method. Though whatever it is I'm sure there's a much better way to do what you're trying to do with other means.